# Autocomplete search in Open Cart

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart framework ,and I do an autocomplete search in the home page it works well ,but it doesn't redirect to the search page with the product that i have search for ,can anyone help ,please 
this code for search.twig ,here is the code for input search and below we have the autocomplete search

```
        <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input-name">{{ entry_name }}             
          </label>
      <input type="text" name="filter_name" 
       value="{{ filter_name }}" placeholder="{{ entry_name }}" 
 class="search_input id="input-name" class="form- control" />
           </div>

       <div class="form-group text-right">
          <button type="button" id="button-filter" class="search_bttn" > Search</button>
        </div>


             <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#button-filter').on('click', function() {
     var url = '';

   var filter_name = $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').prop('value');

 if (filter_name) {
url += '&filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_name);
 }


       location = 'index.php?route=product/search' + url;
      });
    </script>


   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
   // IE and Edge fix!
  $('button[form=\'form-product\']').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#form-product').attr('action', $(this).attr('formaction'));
     });

    $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').autocomplete({
      'source': function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'index.php?route=product/product/autocomplete&filter_name=' +  
          encodeURIComponent(request),
          dataType: 'json',
         success: function(json) {
            response($.map(json, function(item) {
           return {
            label: item['name'],
             value: item['product_id']
           }
           }));
        }
         });
       },
      'select': function(item) {
      $('input[name=\'filter_name\']').val(item['label']);
           }
          });
         </script>
```